# Keras can't load datasets or applications

Tags: python, keras

I am working through the "Deep learning with Python book" from Francois Chollet, but often when I try to import the datasets exactly as they do in the examples, I get this error:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5: None -- [Errno 64] Host is down
```

What does this mean? Can I do anything about it or are the examples in the book outdated...

Comment: The link works (copy-paste it in your browser and it will download the file), so I'd blame the `host is down` error on either your network or a typo/bug in your download script.

Comment: But shouldn't you be able to download datasets or this model directly  from the keras api? @GPhilo

Comment: No idea, I'm not too familiar with the Keras API. All I can say is that the link works ;)

Comment: i have just tried your link and downloaded the weights without any errors. Try downloading it again.

Comment: Host down may be a temporary error. You're supposed to be able to do that, but maybe you've got some proxy limitations, such as when you're inside a company that blocks some things.

Comment: Depending on your company's rules, you might set the `http_proxy` and the `https_proxy` environment vars properly in order for Python to access the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just activate the Internet on kagle kernel

[image]